# UIImagePickerController camera goes blank when it is presented on UICollectionViewCell click

Tags: iphone, ios7, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am facing a weird problem with UIImagePickerController. It goes blank when i present it on my viewController on UICollectionViewCell click.

If i try to present it on click of any button then it works fine.
The way i am doing

```
-(void) LaunchCamera{
   imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

  imagePicker.delegate = self;
  imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

  if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kUserId] integerValue] == 1) {
      imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration=8000.0f;
  }else{
      imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration=20.0f;
  }

   [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Any idea why it is happening ?

Comment: Did you tried to write this on `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

Comment: No actually this collection view is in child viewController and on its click i use to call its delegate method in its parent class and from there i call above method to launch camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys it was my mistake. i was running a small piece of code after presenting UIImagePickerController that's by it was behaving weird. After i removed that piece of code it started working fine.

So its a suggestion to all that do not run any code in same block after presenting UIImagePickerController.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the mediaTypes property in order to capture videos

```
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```

You also need to link your project againgst `MobileCoreServices.framework` to access `kUTTypeMovie`.